# React + Fastify unable to authorize logged in user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, session-cookies, fastify

I use fastify session.
I have a route in fastify that only allows logged in users to access.
I tested it using Thunder Client in VS Code (its like Postman) and it works.
I was able to access the route after logging in. sessionID is always the same as expected.

However, when i use my react front end, every fetch request will always have different sessionID

login code:

```
login: async (username: string, password: string) => {
      try {
        let headersList = {
          Accept: "*/*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        };

        let bodyContent = JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        });

        let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1338/user/login", {
          method: "POST",
          body: bodyContent,
          headers: headersList,
          credentials: 'include'
        });

        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log("cookie: ", response.headers.getSetCookie());

        if (data.user) {
          Cookies.set("session", JSON.stringify(data.user));
          console.log("data: ", Cookies.get('session'))
          console.log(data);
          set({ user: data.user, error: null, isAuthenticated: true });
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Error signing in:",
            data.error
          );
          alert(data.error);
          set({ user: null, error: data.error, isAuthenticated: false });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        set({ user: null, error, isAuthenticated: false });
      }
    }
```

get request code:

```
const getUsers = async (page: number) => {
  const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:1338/user"; 
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();
  queryParams.append("page", `${page}`);
  const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}?${queryParams.toString()}`;
  try {
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });
    console.log(await response.json());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Fetch error:", error);
  }
};

export default getUsers;
```

I have tried fiddling with SameSite on server side, however i do not think its my server side code is causing the problems, because it was working on my tests using thunder client.

So how do i make sure the sessionID is always the same on my front end code?
i have tried credentials: 'include', but that doesn't seem to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just cors not recognizing localhost as a valid origin.
used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it finally works!